# How to know my Arduino core version and its location on my Ubuntu laptop?

Tags: arduino-uno, ubuntu, core-libraries, arduino-makefile

**Bakground:**

When compiling a demo project about e-paper, I got this problem

```
./GxEPD/src/GxIO/GxIO_SPI/GxIO_SPI.h:39:5: error: ‘SPISettings’ does not name a type
     SPISettings _spi_settings;
     ^
```

which on the Internet, people often say your Arduino core is not up-to-date and the one installed from

```
sudo apt install arduino-core
```

is ancient. And you have to install the latest version.

Regardless of whether this solves my original problem or not, I want to have the latest Arduino core on my  laptop.
From arduino.cc I grabbed a zipped file and ran `./install.sh` which did not provide enough results to know what it exactly did. Now, I am concerned that I have multiple installation in several places.

**Main question:**

When I run my make file and it is processed by `arduino-mk`, which version of `arduino-core` is it referred to and where is it located?

I am looking for a full proof method. I do not want to open somewhere from `/` directory accidentally. Because maybe this is not the `arduino-core` in use.

Comment: On Linux install.sh creates a shortcut on Desktop.  A version of AVR boards package is part of IDE installation, but other version and other boards packages managed with Boards Manager are in `~/.arduino15`

Comment: @Juraj,
Actually, I do not use AVR board package. I use make file which calls `avr-gcc`.
I think I could find the answer a bit easier by paying attention to the logs coming out of make such as `/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -MMD -c -mmcu=atmega328p ...` as well as `ARDUINO_DIR = /usr/share/arduino` and `ARDUINO_VERSION = 105`. Now the question is whether my Arduino core is recent?

Comment: @Juraj, at `arduino.cc`, the version of `Arduino Software (IDE)` is `1.6.2`. Is this only the version of IDE or is it the version of core too?

Comment: IDE is at version 1.8.10 on arduino.cc. AVR core is at 1.8.1, but last good version in my opinion is right now 1.6.21

Comment: `/usr/share/arduino/hardware` is the location of boards packages bundled with IDE

Answer (score 1):

The ancient version installed by apt lives in
`/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino`.

If you download and unpack a recent version, it will stay wherever you
left it. For example, I have an Arduino core in
`/home/edgar/Downloads/arduino-1.8.10/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino`.
The installation script doesn't really install those files. It does
install some icons and desktop shortcuts, but neither the core nor the
Arduino IDE. Instead, it assumes the downloaded package will stay
wherever it was when you ran the script.

If you want a somewhat cleaner installation, I suggest you move the
package to `/opt`, recursively chown it to root, and run the setup script
there. The core will then be in
`/opt/arduino-<version>/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Then how to tell `arduino-mk` to which version to use?

Comment: Can I insall it in a temp directory and then overwrite it on the ancient arduino core?

Comment: @ar2015: Read the comments at the beginning of `/usr/share/arduino/Arduino.mk`. They tell you the variables you can use for selection the version. It would seem `ARDUINO_DIR` is the main one.